# Proving that $c + a_1 \sin(x) + b_1 \cos(x) + a_2 \sin(2x) + b_2 \cos(2x) + \dots + a_n\sin(nx) + b_n\cos(nx) \equiv 0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let's consider $c, a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n, b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n \in \mathbb R$ and function

$$g:[a, b] \ni x \rightarrow c + a_1 \sin(x) + b_1 \cos(x) + a_2 \sin(2x) + b_2 \cos(2x) + \dots + a_n\sin(nx) + b_n\cos(nx) \in \mathbb R$$

where $[a, b] \subset [0, 2 \pi)$

Moreover we have different numbers $z_1, z_2, \dots, z_{2n}, z_{2n + 1} \in [a, b]$ for such $g(z_i) = 0$, $i = 1,2,\dots,\color{red}{n}$. I want to prove that out of those conditions we have that $g \equiv 0$.

**My work so far**

I wanted somehow to use properties of trygonometrics functions.

I rewrite some properties as:

$$g(x) \le c + \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i + \sum_{i = 1}^n b_i$$

$$g(x) \ge c - \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i - \sum_{i = 1}^n b_i$$

and that $g(0) = c + \sum_{i = 1}^n b_i$. I'm almost sure that we have somehow to use cyclic property of trygonometric functions i.e. $\sin(2k\pi + x) = \sin(x)$ and $\cos(x) = \cos(x + 2k\pi)$ but I don't see exactly where can we use it. Could you please give me a hand in proving this?

Comment: Perhaps, you can rewrite everything in terms of complex numbers. Namely, put $z=\cos x+i\sin x$ and rewrite the equalities in terms of $z$ (how?). Then, you can obtain a polynomial in $z$ with $2n$ roots. Not sure, what to nex, though.

Comment: By the way, I realised that in the present form the statement is incorrect: take $g(x)=\sin x$ and $z_1=0,z_2=\pi$.

Comment: Yes, I realized that the statment is false with $2n$ roots, but it will be correct if we have $(2n   + 1)$ because then the polynomial that you were talking about has to be 0 polynomial